# How to OTA Updation via HTTPS(ESP8266)?

Tags: arduino, esp8266, ota

On esp8266, how can I update the bin file in ESP8266 from a webserver  using HTTPS?

I have tried, but I get an http update failure error.

[Error debug in Arduino ide serial window](https://i.stack.imgur.com/E9hfs.jpg)

```css
/ Check for a firmware update
  LOG("Checking for firmware, same URL.\r\n");
  Result = ESPhttpUpdate.update(HTTPSURL,Fingerprint);

  // if successful, ESP will restart
  LOG("Oh noes, update failed!\r\nResult:");
  LOG(Result);
  LOG("\r\n");

  switch(Result) {
    case HTTP_UPDATE_FAILED:
        sprintf((char *)Buffer, "Update failed, error %d: %s\r\n", ESPhttpUpdate.getLastError(), ESPhttpUpdate.getLastErrorString().c_str());
        LOG((char *)Buffer);
        break;
    case HTTP_UPDATE_NO_UPDATES:
        LOG("No update available.\r\n");
        break;
    case HTTP_UPDATE_OK:
        LOG("You shouldn't see this message because I should be rebooting :)\r\n");
        break;
  }
```

Comment: Can you please post the error or code you're using here?